# Puppeteer - select based on text children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, puppeteer

If I have the following:

```
<div>Hello world</div>
```

How can I select the div using "Hello world" as the query value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with jQuery's [**`:contains()`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector that ***selects all elements that contain the specified text***:

```js
console.log($('div:contains(Hello world)').get(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you can use XPath:

```js
$x('//div[text()="Hello world"]');
```

or, if you're not necessarily looking for the exact match:

```js
$x('//div[text()[contains(., "Hello world")]]');
```